# AVR bitwise C operations

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, avr

I have a question about ATMEGA328P programming in Atmel Studio 6.1.

Isn't it faster to assign a binary to register than making shift operation?

If I understand correctly, but please correct this!!

Let's say:

```
DDRC = 0b11001100;
```

I have to check initial bit condition before making bitwise operation before shifting any a bit to location?
For example

```
DDRC |= (1<<DDRC0);
```

and we get:

```
  11001100
  10011001
=
  11011101
```

Is this right?
If we know anyway a bit combination to simply write and maybe it's faster and simpler?:

```
0b11001101
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. Have you looked at the machine code that your C code generates and determined that it is suboptimal?

Comment: Atmega328P, AVR-GCC compiler from atmel studio. If i'am not mistaken. Question is about bitwise operations, on 8bit registers. What is better to get there walues and make bitwise opperations to change them or to change once according to needs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for the sake of the demonstration:

here are two code compiled with avr-gcc-4.7.2:

```
void main() {
    DDRC |= (1<<5);
}

and another:

void main() {
    DDRC |= 0b100000;
}

 % diff -s t2.s t.s
Files t2.s and t.s are identical
```

that's because `1<<N` is detected at compile time, and transform to its constant equivalent, making both expressions identical when sent to the microcontroller.

About operations, please have a look at truth tables:

```
| a b -> a&b |        | a b -> a|b |
| 0 0    0   |        | 0 0    0   |
| 0 1    0   |        | 0 1    1   |
| 1 0    0   |        | 1 0    1   |
| 1 1    1   |        | 1 1    1   |
```

the hint to remember both truth tables is the following:

- if one of the operands is a `0` and you're doing a `&`, then the result will be `0` *(force to 0)*
- if one of the operands is a `1` and you're doing a `|`, then the result will be `1` *(force to 1)*

So if you take an example a bit more complicated:

```
101010 | 010101 = 111111
101010 & 010101 = 000000
```

and finaly, when you want to set a bit:

```
REGISTER = 00000001
REGISTER |= 1<<5      <=> REGISTER = 00000001 | 00100000
REGISTER == 00100001
```

if you want to reset that bit:

```
REGISTER &= ~(1<<5)   <=> REGISTER = 00100001 & ~(00100000)  <=> REGISTER = 00100001 & 11011111
REGISTER == 00000001
```

I hope it's making more sense… Though you'd better lookup for a course on combinatory logics, which is the basic to perfectly handle when doing embedded programming.

Now to answer your question:

> *if we know anyway a bit combination to simply write and maybe its faster and simpler?:*

it's not necessarily faster, and not really simpler.

Consider the following made up register FOO:

```
  7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
[ A | B | C | D | W | X | Y | Z ]
```

now consider that we have build a header that has preprocessor variables with the right values:

```
FOOZ = 0
FOOY = 1
FOOX = 2
FOOW = 3
FOOD = 4
FOOC = 5
FOOB = 6
FOOA = 7
```

and now we need to set up `A`, `C` and 'X' bits, which can be done as follows:

```
FOO |= 1<<FOOA | 1<<FOOC | 1<<FOOX
```

instead of:

```
FOO |= 0b10100100
```

which could more easily lead to errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks, don't be mad! I was confused that it shits initial register, not creating new variable to  or xor and or anything to make operation and return value to register. Thank you.!

Comment: Very vell explaned and commented, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is slower.

The reason for the usual syntax like `DDRC |= (1<<DDRC0);` is that the right side contains compile time constants. The compiler will convert it to a number before the processor sees it, so the processor doesn't perform the shift.

As for using the `|=` assignment operator, there may be an extra read operation. But the cost for efficiency for a one time assignment is vastly less than the cost to maintain the source code.

I'm not sure what you are doing with the arithmetic in your question. The statement takes the original contents of `DDRC` and ors it with something like `0b00000001` (where the 1 is in the `DDRC0` position), and assigns it back to `DDRC`.

Comment: So there i have a question is there a safe bitwise operator to change only one bit to 1 from 0 or from 0 to 1 if i don't know other values. Sorry I have a litle knowledge in bitwise opperations. Thanks for supporting and deep explanation.

Comment: that's exactly what the logical or/`|` (force to one) and logical and/`&` (force to 0) do! Look up the [wikipedia page for truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

Comment: So if i shift to much i will shift out other valiables? and get bad result in register configuration isn't? wrong?

Comment: The shift operator is acting on the constant `1`. There are no variables being shifted.

Comment: Ok, can you edit post so even i could understand.. with examples? how this register is shifted, what is shifted and how it changes. because i still confused. 0b01100110|= (1<<0) it becames =01100110|00000001?  and (1<<3) 01100110|00000100 is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are more efficient ways of setting a bit and clearing a bit on many microcontrollers that does not involve the other bits, ie you don't have to use OR and AND to maintain the other bits.

There are AVR machine instructions to set a bit and clear a bit of a register, namely "SBR" and "CBR".  Also see "CBI" and "SBI" if you need to set an IO register.  I'm not sure if the AVR compiler is smart enough to convert C-style operations which operate on bytes into individual bit statements. But usually there are intrinsics to do this. I'm not an AVR user.

Perhaps you can use gcc `asm()` to insert SBR and CBR. But I wouldn't bother with this unless you need to save a cycle in an ISR. It's not worth the headache.

See page 127 here http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf
and page 272 here http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404-2008/docs/avr-libc-user-manual-1.4.6.pdf